# Residue derivation for integral of sin x/x

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am trying to integrate $e^(iz)/z$ over a rectangle contour from $-R$ to $r$ along the real axis and a small semicircle from -r to r and then goes along the real axis to R and then completes the rectangle by going from R to R+i by a straight line and then to R-i along a straight line and then back down to -R. I have expressed this integral in terms of its 6 parts. I am having trouble showing that 3 of them vanish to 0 as r->0 and R->infinity (the three straight lines of the rectangle without any semicircle) as part of my proof. Any tips to go about this?

Comment: Why a rectangle and not a semicircle, say? If you take the semicircle $\;G_R:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;:\;|z|=R\;,\;\;\text{Im}(z)\ge 0\}\;$ , then $$\left|\int_{G_R}\frac{e^{iz}}zdz\right|\le\frac{e^{-\text{Im}(z)}}{R}\cdot\pi R \xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}0$$

Comment: My professor said to try using a rectangle as an exercise, which is why I am trying to do this but I am just having trouble bounding the modulus of the function over the 3 segments.